# Can we have multiple properties under a single property key in No4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a node with a Property key that can have multiple values.

For example **jobs**:"HSBC","American Bank", "Russian Bank", "Indian Bank"

Is there a way to do this via Neo4j using cypher?

Also, if there is, can I edit a node to include the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can have a [list](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-values) of Strings-

```
CREATE (n:Person {jobs:["HSBC","American Bank", "Russian Bank", "Indian Bank"]})
```

List Operators: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-operators-list

Comment: Thank you. Although I did not understand why exactly you provided this link.

Comment: The first link lists valid properties, and the second shows operators that you can use to manage your list